# How to get a shaded bar in beamer

Tags: beamer

I would like to add a shaded bar at the bottom of a beamer presentation, with my name and the frame number.

Eventually I'd like to center the frametitle with a line below to separate from the main part.

Look at the image to see what I mean. [image]

I can add the background image, but I cannot do the bar at the bottom. I tried to define the footline myself, failed so I tried with an existing outertheme.

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\usefonttheme{serif,professionalfonts}

\definecolor{orangeiut}{RGB}{247,158,4} 

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=96mm,width=128mm]{nombidon}{fond}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\pgfuseimage{nombidon}}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orangeiut}
\setbeamerfont{itemize item}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\ding{226}}

\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{manfnt}
\usepackage{pifont}
```

Anybody knows how to solve that problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    every picture/.prefix style={
        execute at begin picture=\shorthandoff{;}
    }
}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\usefonttheme{serif,professionalfonts}

\definecolor{orangeiut}{RGB}{247,158,4} 

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt}}}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\huge}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=96mm,width=128mm]{nombidon}{fond}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\pgfuseimage{nombidon}}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orangeiut}
\setbeamerfont{itemize item}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\ding{226}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode
  \raisebox{-1pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}\par\nointerlineskip%
  \hspace*{0.6pt}\tikz[]\node[,anchor=south,text width=\the\dimexpr\paperwidth-13.2pt\relax,top color=orangeiut!10,bottom color=orangeiut!90!black,inner xsep=6pt,inner ysep=10pt,fill opacity=0.75]%
    {\insertshortauthor\hfill%
    \insertframenumber};%
}

\author{The author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test title}
test
\begin{itemize}
\item First.
\item Second.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The bottom bar was built using a node with shading; I also used a redefinition of the `frametitle` attributes.

The lines

```
\tikzset{
    every picture/.prefix style={
        execute at begin picture=\shorthandoff{;}
    }
}
```

are needed since the `french` module for `babel` is used; this module makes `;` active, so it is necessary to deactivate this shorthand in `tikzpicture`s. For other `babel` modules those lines are not required.

Comment: Really nice solution.

Comment: I get an error - `! Argument of \tikz@next has an extra }.` when I try to compile that code. I tried clearing all generated files but the error persists. I'm using `pdflatex` to compile.

Comment: @cfr Ah, I forget that I'm using version 3.0 of PGF. With version 2.10 you need to append `\the` to `\dimexpr` (I've edited my answer with this change). Please let me know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't fix it here. I still get the same error (and if I try to continue it complains of a runaway argument).

Comment: @cfr Fixed! (I hope). The problem is the `french` module for `babel` which makes `;` active. Deactivating the shorthand for every `tikzpicture` solved the problem. Thanks for noticing the problem!

Comment: That works! Thanks, too, for the explanation. I've never needed to use `french`.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted !

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am sorry but there is still something I don't understand. It seems to me that you control the height of the bar with the inner ysep value. But 10 pt is pretty short and still the bar looks good enough. Can you explain to me how it works ? Thanks

Comment: @antoine the `inner ysep` is the vertical separation between the contents and the top/bottom border of the node. The real height of the node will then be given by the height of its content plus `20pt` (= `2* (inner ysep)`).